# jquery fancybox background with an image

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-plugins, fancybox

I want to apply at the jQuery plugin called fancybox an image background with a pixel 1x1 white with 0.9 of transparency.

I have create the pixel in photoshop and when I insert into background of the fancy doesn't appear, the background is empty without error on firebug like image not found or something like that. Here is the css code of fancybox:
(the part that I have changed is in #fancybox-outer and #fancybox-content) I have tried background and background-image nothing, help me

```
  /*
     * FancyBox - jQuery Plugin
     * Simple and fancy lightbox alternative
     *
     * Examples and documentation at: http://fancybox.net
     * 
     * Copyright (c) 2008 - 2010 Janis Skarnelis
     * That said, it is hardly a one-person project. Many people have submitted bugs, code, and offered their advice freely. Their support is greatly appreciated.
     * 
     * Version: 1.3.4 (11/11/2010)
     * Requires: jQuery v1.3+
     *
     * Dual licensed under the MIT and GPL licenses:
     *   http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
     *   http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html
     */

    #fancybox-loading {
        position: fixed;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        width: 40px;
        height: 40px;
        margin-top: -20px;
        margin-left: -20px;
        cursor: pointer;
        overflow: hidden;
        z-index: 1104;
        display: none;
    }

    #fancybox-loading div {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 40px;
        height: 480px;
        background-image: url('fancybox.png');
    }

    #fancybox-overlay {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        z-index: 1100;
        display: none;
    }

    #fancybox-tmp {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        border: 0;
        overflow: auto;
        display: none;
    }

    #fancybox-wrap {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        padding: 20px;
        z-index: 1101;
        outline: none;
        display: none;
    }

    #fancybox-outer {
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background: url(sfondo_fancy.png) repeat-x repeat-y;
    }

    #fancybox-content {
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        padding: 0;
        outline: none;
        position: relative;
        overflow: hidden;
        z-index: 1102;
        background: url(sfondo_fancy.png) repeat-x repeat-y;
    }

    #fancybox-hide-sel-frame {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background: transparent;
        z-index: 1101;
    }

    #fancybox-close {
        position: absolute;
        top: -15px;
        right: -15px;
        width: 30px;
        height: 30px;
        background: transparent url('fancybox.png') -40px 0px;
        cursor: pointer;
        z-index: 1103;
        display: none;
    }

    #fancybox-error {
        color: #444;
        font: normal 12px/20px Arial;
        padding: 14px;
        margin: 0;
    }

    #fancybox-img {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        border: none;
        outline: none;
        line-height: 0;
        vertical-align: top;
    }

    #fancybox-frame {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        border: none;
        display: block;
    }

    #fancybox-left, #fancybox-right {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0px;
        height: 100%;
        width: 35%;
        cursor: pointer;
        outline: none;
        background: transparent url('blank.gif');
        z-index: 1102;
        display: none;
    }

    #fancybox-left {
        left: 0px;
    }

    #fancybox-right {
        right: 0px;
    }

    #fancybox-left-ico, #fancybox-right-ico {
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: -9999px;
        width: 30px;
        height: 30px;
        margin-top: -15px;
        cursor: pointer;
        z-index: 1102;
        display: block;
    }

    #fancybox-left-ico {
        background-image: url('fancybox.png');
        background-position: -40px -30px;
    }

    #fancybox-right-ico {
        background-image: url('fancybox.png');
        background-position: -40px -60px;
    }

    #fancybox-left:hover, #fancybox-right:hover {
        visibility: visible; /* IE6 */
    }

    #fancybox-left:hover span {
        left: 20px;
    }

    #fancybox-right:hover span {
        left: auto;
        right: 20px;
    }

    .fancybox-bg {
        position: absolute;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        border: 0;
        width: 20px;
        height: 20px;
        z-index: 1001;
    }

    #fancybox-bg-n {
        top: -20px;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        background-image: url('fancybox-x.png');
    }

    #fancybox-bg-ne {
        top: -20px;
        right: -20px;
        background-image: url('fancybox.png');
        background-position: -40px -162px;
    }

    #fancybox-bg-e {
        top: 0;
        right: -20px;
        height: 100%;
        background-image: url('fancybox-y.png');
        background-position: -20px 0px;
    }

    #fancybox-bg-se {
        bottom: -20px;
        right: -20px;
        background-image: url('fancybox.png');
        background-position: -40px -182px; 
    }

    #fancybox-bg-s {
        bottom: -20px;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        background-image: url('fancybox-x.png');
        background-position: 0px -20px;
    }

    #fancybox-bg-sw {
        bottom: -20px;
        left: -20px;
        background-image: url('fancybox.png');
        background-position: -40px -142px;
    }

    #fancybox-bg-w {
        top: 0;
        left: -20px;
        height: 100%;
        background-image: url('fancybox-y.png');
    }

    #fancybox-bg-nw {
        top: -20px;
        left: -20px;
        background-image: url('fancybox.png');
        background-position: -40px -122px;
    }

    #fancybox-title {
        font-family: Helvetica;
        font-size: 12px;
        z-index: 1102;
    }

    .fancybox-title-inside {
        padding-bottom: 10px;
        text-align: center;
        color: #333;
        background: #fff;
        position: relative;
    }

    .fancybox-title-outside {
        padding-top: 10px;
        color: #fff;
    }

    .fancybox-title-over {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        color: #FFF;
        text-align: left;
    }

    #fancybox-title-over {
        padding: 10px;
        background-image: url('fancy_title_over.png');
        display: block;
    }

    .fancybox-title-float {
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        bottom: -20px;
        height: 32px;
    }

    #fancybox-title-float-wrap {
        border: none;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        width: auto;
    }

    #fancybox-title-float-wrap td {
        border: none;
        white-space: nowrap;
    }

    #fancybox-title-float-left {
        padding: 0 0 0 15px;
        background: url('fancybox.png') -40px -90px no-repeat;
    }

    #fancybox-title-float-main {
        color: #FFF;
        line-height: 29px;
        font-weight: bold;
        padding: 0 0 3px 0;
        background: url('fancybox-x.png') 0px -40px;
    }

    #fancybox-title-float-right {
        padding: 0 0 0 15px;
        background: url('fancybox.png') -55px -90px no-repeat;
    }

    /* IE6 */

    .fancybox-ie6 #fancybox-close { background: transparent; filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='fancybox/fancy_close.png', sizingMethod='scale'); }

    .fancybox-ie6 #fancybox-left-ico { background: transparent; filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='fancybox/fancy_nav_left.png', sizingMethod='scale'); }
    .fancybox-ie6 #fancybox-right-ico { background: transparent; filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='fancybox/fancy_nav_right.png', sizingMethod='scale'); }

    .fancybox-ie6 #fancybox-title-over { background: transparent; filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='fancybox/fancy_title_over.png', sizingMethod='scale'); zoom: 1; }
    .fancybox-ie6 #fancybox-title-float-left { background: transparent; filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='fancybox/fancy_title_left.png', sizingMethod='scale'); }
    .fancybox-ie6 #fancybox-title-float-main { background: transparent; filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='fancybox/fancy_title_main.png', sizingMethod='scale'); }
    .fancybox-ie6 #fancybox-title-float-right { background: transparent; filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='fancybox/fancy_title_right.png', sizingMethod='scale'); }

    .fancybox-ie6 #fancybox-bg-w, .fancybox-ie6 #fancybox-bg-e, .fancybox-ie6 #fancybox-left, .fancybox-ie6 #fancybox-right, #fancybox-hide-sel-frame {
        height: expression(this.parentNode.clientHeight + "px");
    }

    #fancybox-loading.fancybox-ie6 {
        position: absolute; margin-top: 0;
        top: expression( (-20 + (document.documentElement.clientHeight ? document.documentElement.clientHeight/2 : document.body.clientHeight/2 ) + ( ignoreMe = document.documentElement.scrollTop ? document.documentElement.scrollTop : document.body.scrollTop )) + 'px');
    }

    #fancybox-loading.fancybox-ie6 div  { background: transparent; filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='fancybox/fancy_loading.png', sizingMethod='scale'); }

    /* IE6, IE7, IE8 */

    .fancybox-ie .fancybox-bg { background: transparent !important; }

    .fancybox-ie #fancybox-bg-n { filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='fancybox/fancy_shadow_n.png', sizingMethod='scale'); }
    .fancybox-ie #fancybox-bg-ne { filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='fancybox/fancy_shadow_ne.png', sizingMethod='scale'); }
    .fancybox-ie #fancybox-bg-e { filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='fancybox/fancy_shadow_e.png', sizingMethod='scale'); }
    .fancybox-ie #fancybox-bg-se { filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='fancybox/fancy_shadow_se.png', sizingMethod='scale'); }
    .fancybox-ie #fancybox-bg-s { filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='fancybox/fancy_shadow_s.png', sizingMethod='scale'); }
    .fancybox-ie #fancybox-bg-sw { filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='fancybox/fancy_shadow_sw.png', sizingMethod='scale'); }
    .fancybox-ie #fancybox-bg-w { filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='fancybox/fancy_shadow_w.png', sizingMethod='scale'); }
    .fancybox-ie #fancybox-bg-nw { filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='fancybox/fancy_shadow_nw.png', sizingMethod='scale'); }
```

Comment: hopefully you need to tweak with your plugin code

Comment: Add some html for this. And try removing repeat-x repeat-y there is no need of this if you want to repeat this image in both direction.

Comment: Are you  using this image `sfondo_fancy.png` as a background? If yes then in which folder both the image `sfondo_fancy.png` and css `Fancybox CSS` are placed?

Comment: In the same directory but isn't a problem of folder because I have browse the image and it founded the image

Comment: for overlay? if is it you can try: `$(".fancybox").fancybox({ ... helpers: {overlay : { opacity : 0.9, css : {'background-color' : '#000'}} ...`

Comment: I have added this into my file php but nothing, the background is empty (transparent)
$("a.iframe").fancybox({
  'type'   : 'inline',
  'width'   : 800,
  'height'  : 550,
  'autoDimensions': false,
  'autoScale'  : false,
   'overlay' : { opacity : 0.9, css : {'background-color' : '#fff'}}
 });

Comment: The overlay is for all the page not only for the content of my iframe, @AlexBall

Comment: Try this: `$("a.iframe").fancybox({ 'type' : 'inline', 'width' : 800, 'height' : 550, 'autoDimensions': false, 'autoScale' : false, 'overlayColor' : '#fff', 'overlayOpacity': 0.9 });`

Comment: no it apply for all the page the background not only in the content unfortunately...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is in the css that I have modified the content and outer with background transparent without shadow like this:

```
/*
 * FancyBox - jQuery Plugin
 * Simple and fancy lightbox alternative
 *
 * Examples and documentation at: http://fancybox.net
 * 
 * Copyright (c) 2008 - 2010 Janis Skarnelis
 * That said, it is hardly a one-person project. Many people have submitted bugs, code, and offered their advice freely. Their support is greatly appreciated.
 * 
 * Version: 1.3.4 (11/11/2010)
 * Requires: jQuery v1.3+
 *
 * Dual licensed under the MIT and GPL licenses:
 *   http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
 *   http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html
 */

#fancybox-loading {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    margin-top: -20px;
    margin-left: -20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 1104;
    display: none;
}

#fancybox-loading div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 40px;
    height: 480px;
    background-image: url('fancybox.png');
}

#fancybox-overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1100;
    display: none;
}

#fancybox-tmp {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
    overflow: auto;
    display: none;
}

#fancybox-wrap {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 20px;
    z-index: 1101;
    outline: none;
    display: none;
    background: url('sfondo_fancy.png') repeat;


}

#fancybox-outer {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    /*background: url('sfondo_fancy.png') repeat;*/
    /*background:#fff;
    opacity:0.9;
    /*background: url('sfondo_fancy.png');*/
    background:transparent;
}

#fancybox-content {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    padding: 0;
    outline: none;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 1102;
    /*background: url('sfondo_fancy.png') repeat;*/
    /*background:#fff;
    opacity:0.9;
    /*background:url(sfondo_fancy.png) !important;*/
    background:transparent;
}

#fancybox-hide-sel-frame {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: transparent;
    z-index: 1101;
}

#fancybox-close {
    position: absolute;
    top: -15px;
    right: -15px;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    background: transparent url('fancybox.png') -40px 0px;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 1103;
    display: none;
}

#fancybox-error {
    color: #444;
    font: normal 12px/20px Arial;
    padding: 14px;
    margin: 0;
}

#fancybox-img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    line-height: 0;
    vertical-align: top;
}

#fancybox-frame {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: none;
    display: block;
}

#fancybox-left, #fancybox-right {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 35%;
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: none;
    background: transparent url('blank.gif');
    z-index: 1102;
    display: none;
}

#fancybox-left {
    left: 0px;
}

#fancybox-right {
    right: 0px;
}

#fancybox-left-ico, #fancybox-right-ico {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: -9999px;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    margin-top: -15px;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 1102;
    display: block;
}

#fancybox-left-ico {
    background-image: url('fancybox.png');
    background-position: -40px -30px;
}

#fancybox-right-ico {
    background-image: url('fancybox.png');
    background-position: -40px -60px;
}

#fancybox-left:hover, #fancybox-right:hover {
    visibility: visible; /* IE6 */
}

#fancybox-left:hover span {
    left: 20px;
}

#fancybox-right:hover span {
    left: auto;
    right: 20px;
}

.fancybox-bg {
    position: absolute;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
    /*width: 20px;
    height: 20px;*/
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    z-index: 1001;
}

#fancybox-bg-n {
    top: -20px;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url('fancybox-x.png');
}

#fancybox-bg-ne {
    top: -20px;
    right: -20px;
    background-image: url('fancybox.png');
    background-position: -40px -162px;
}

#fancybox-bg-e {
    top: 0;
    right: -20px;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url('fancybox-y.png');
    background-position: -20px 0px;
}

#fancybox-bg-se {
    bottom: -20px;
    right: -20px;
    background-image: url('fancybox.png');
    background-position: -40px -182px; 
}

#fancybox-bg-s {
    bottom: -20px;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url('fancybox-x.png');
    background-position: 0px -20px;
}

#fancybox-bg-sw {
    bottom: -20px;
    left: -20px;
    background-image: url('fancybox.png');
    background-position: -40px -142px;
}

#fancybox-bg-w {
    top: 0;
    left: -20px;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url('fancybox-y.png');
}

#fancybox-bg-nw {
    top: -20px;
    left: -20px;
    background-image: url('fancybox.png');
    background-position: -40px -122px;
}

#fancybox-title {
    font-family: Helvetica;
    font-size: 12px;
    z-index: 1102;
}

.fancybox-title-inside {
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #333;
    background: #fff;
    position: relative;
}

.fancybox-title-outside {
    padding-top: 10px;
    color: #fff;
}

.fancybox-title-over {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    color: #FFF;
    text-align: left;
}

#fancybox-title-over {
    padding: 10px;
    background-image: url('fancy_title_over.png');
    display: block;
}

.fancybox-title-float {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: -20px;
    height: 32px;
}

#fancybox-title-float-wrap {
    border: none;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: auto;
}

#fancybox-title-float-wrap td {
    border: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

#fancybox-title-float-left {
    padding: 0 0 0 15px;
    background: url('fancybox.png') -40px -90px no-repeat;
}

#fancybox-title-float-main {
    color: #FFF;
    line-height: 29px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 0 0 3px 0;
    background: url('fancybox-x.png') 0px -40px;
}

#fancybox-title-float-right {
    padding: 0 0 0 15px;
    background: url('fancybox.png') -55px -90px no-repeat;
}

/* IE6 */

.fancybox-ie6 #fancybox-close { background: transparent; filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='fancybox/fancy_close.png', sizingMethod='scale'); }

.fancybox-ie6 #fancybox-left-ico { background: transparent; filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='fancybox/fancy_nav_left.png', sizingMethod='scale'); }
.fancybox-ie6 #fancybox-right-ico { background: transparent; filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='fancybox/fancy_nav_right.png', sizingMethod='scale'); }

.fancybox-ie6 #fancybox-title-over { background: transparent; filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='fancybox/fancy_title_over.png', sizingMethod='scale'); zoom: 1; }
.fancybox-ie6 #fancybox-title-float-left { background: transparent; filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='fancybox/fancy_title_left.png', sizingMethod='scale'); }
.fancybox-ie6 #fancybox-title-float-main { background: transparent; filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='fancybox/fancy_title_main.png', sizingMethod='scale'); }
.fancybox-ie6 #fancybox-title-float-right { background: transparent; filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='fancybox/fancy_title_right.png', sizingMethod='scale'); }

.fancybox-ie6 #fancybox-bg-w, .fancybox-ie6 #fancybox-bg-e, .fancybox-ie6 #fancybox-left, .fancybox-ie6 #fancybox-right, #fancybox-hide-sel-frame {
    height: expression(this.parentNode.clientHeight + "px");
}

#fancybox-loading.fancybox-ie6 {
    position: absolute; margin-top: 0;
    top: expression( (-20 + (document.documentElement.clientHeight ? document.documentElement.clientHeight/2 : document.body.clientHeight/2 ) + ( ignoreMe = document.documentElement.scrollTop ? document.documentElement.scrollTop : document.body.scrollTop )) + 'px');
}

#fancybox-loading.fancybox-ie6 div  { background: transparent; filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='fancybox/fancy_loading.png', sizingMethod='scale'); }

/* IE6, IE7, IE8 */

.fancybox-ie .fancybox-bg { background: transparent !important; }

.fancybox-ie #fancybox-bg-n { filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='fancybox/fancy_shadow_n.png', sizingMethod='scale'); }
.fancybox-ie #fancybox-bg-ne { filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='fancybox/fancy_shadow_ne.png', sizingMethod='scale'); }
.fancybox-ie #fancybox-bg-e { filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='fancybox/fancy_shadow_e.png', sizingMethod='scale'); }
.fancybox-ie #fancybox-bg-se { filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='fancybox/fancy_shadow_se.png', sizingMethod='scale'); }
.fancybox-ie #fancybox-bg-s { filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='fancybox/fancy_shadow_s.png', sizingMethod='scale'); }
.fancybox-ie #fancybox-bg-sw { filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='fancybox/fancy_shadow_sw.png', sizingMethod='scale'); }
.fancybox-ie #fancybox-bg-w { filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='fancybox/fancy_shadow_w.png', sizingMethod='scale'); }
.fancybox-ie #fancybox-bg-nw { filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='fancybox/fancy_shadow_nw.png', sizingMethod='scale'); }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a 1x1 pixel image, you can use a color instead of an image as background. Because that image has only one color.

Comment: Yes but when you apply the opacity you apply that to te text into into the fancybox too, not only in the background

Comment: Take a look at @Alex Ball comment.

Comment: No his solution isn't for me changing the overlay is for all the page not only for the content

Answer (score 0):

Add the background image to #fancybox-wrap

```
#fancybox-wrap {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 20px;
    z-index: 1101;
    outline: none;
    display: none;
    background: url('sfondo_fancy.png') repeat;
}
```

Comment: No in this mode you apply out the fancybox the background of the content, the background of wrap have to be transparent, only the content have to apply the background

Comment: OK, try without deleting what I told you, keep them both there.

Comment: No, the wrap take the background the content no it reamins white without opacity and you can see the sahdow of the content in the wrap

Comment: Remove the shadow image from the stylesheet, and try to find any white background color, it could be in different forms: `#fff`, `#ffffff`, or `white`. Remove the white background as well, and replace it with your own picture.